# Spatial Object Mesh Observer: Mesh Data

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens

For an academy project I have to find parts of a object (location / angle relative to the object ). The object is marked with a QR-code.

Currently I'm stuck on the basics. I scanned a room and load this room with "Spatial Object Mesh Observer".

But this observer gives no relevant information:
The observer does not attempt to find 3D model LODs when sending the meshes to the application.

Someone a hint where I could start?

Scanned Room with a box ( object to find ):

[image: room]

```
var observer = CoreServices.GetSpatialAwarenessSystemDataProvider<IMixedRealitySpatialAwarenessMeshObserver>();

// Loop through all known Meshes
foreach (SpatialAwarenessMeshObject meshObject in observer.Meshes.Values)
{
    Mesh mesh = meshObject.Filter.mesh;
    var vertices = mesh.vertices;
    // mesh.vertexCount -> 15978
    // mesh.vertices -> empty
    // mesh.triangles -> empty
    // Do something with the Mesh object
}
```

Edit: 29.04.2021

- Unity: Unity 2019.4.21f1
- MRTK: 2.6.1
  Everything seems to be loaded correctly and the triangles are recognized in an external tool.
  However, this information is not available in Unity.
  [image]
  [image]

Comment: Did you mean you can't get vertices and triangles property from a mesh object? Or it can't recognize your 3D model? Besides, what version of Unity and MRTK you are using?

Comment: I added the information. Yes there are no information about vertices and triangles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From our understanding, you can't obtain the vertices and triangles property of Spatial Mesh at the runtime. So, we try to make some modifications based on the `SpatialAwarenessMeshDemo` scene (Assets/MRTK/Examples/Demos/SpatialAwareness/Scenes) to reproduce this issue. We added the following code to the `ToggleObservers()` method and made it to be invoked when the sphere is clicked.

```
        var observer = CoreServices.GetSpatialAwarenessSystemDataProvider<IMixedRealitySpatialAwarenessMeshObserver>();

        foreach (SpatialAwarenessMeshObject meshObject in observer.Meshes.Values)
        {
            Mesh mesh = meshObject.Filter.mesh;
            Debug.Log(mesh.vertexCount);
            Debug.Log(mesh.vertices);
            Debug.Log(mesh.triangles);
        }
```

After our test, everything works well both in the HoloLens2 Device and Unity Holographic Remoting, it always outputs the expected value. So we recommend that you check for updates in Settings to see If there is a system update available for HoloLens 2. Then follow our steps to make a simple test to see if that works. This may help you locate the problem in your project.

Comment: One difference is I use the "SpatialObjectMeshObserver" with a saved room and not the WindowsMixedRealitySpatialMeshObserver.

Answer (score 0):

I moved the code to "void OnBecameVisible()", now the information are available